# Jquery live search, doesnt exit if statement once content is removed from the input

Tags: jquery, livesearch

I am currently in a final team project for my training as a web developer. And i did wrote a live search code for our application and it works as intended until the point i remove the content from the input. The code stays sometimes in the if statement to remove the append. And i dont see why. Does someone know?

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){

 var check = 0;

 $("#getQuestions").on("keyup", function(){
    check++;

    var inputLength = $("#getQuestions").val().length;

    if (check === 3 || inputLength === 0) {

        $(".liveSearch").remove();

    }
    if (inputLength >= 1) {

        if(check === 3 ){

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/getQuestions",
                data: {"question": $("#getQuestions").val()}

            }).done(function(response){

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {

                    var id = response[i].id;
                    var title = response[i].title;
                    $("#listQuestions").append('<div class="liveSearch"><a href="/question?id='+id +'""' + '>' + title + '</a></div>' );

                }

                check = 0;

            });

        }
    }


 });


});
```

I appreciate the help.

Have a nice day.

Comment: Can you please show your full code? And if possible create a fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating things by using a count var. Right now your ajax call only triggers for every 3 key ups (which means issues with for instance pressing shift 3 times will trigger it or pressing and holding a letter will only increase count by 1).

By using keypress and a timer instead, you'll get the following code:

```
$(function(){
  var timer;
  $("#getQuestions").on("keypress", function(){
    if ($("#getQuestions").val().length == 0) {
      $(".liveSearch").remove();
    }
    if ($("#getQuestions").val().length > 0) {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        $(".liveSearch").remove();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/getQuestions",
          data: {"question": $("#getQuestions").val()}
        }).done(function(response){
          for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $("#listQuestions").append('<div class="liveSearch"><a href="/question?id=' + response[i].id + '">' + response[i].title + '</a></div>');
          }
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, i appreciate the help! Yeah This works already alot smoother with a timer. But now it doesnt remove the content anymore if the input is empty.

Comment: How do i do that? Dont see any option here nor on my profile.